# Writing a Proxy/Caching server using Lua!

Tags: http, sockets, proxy, lua

I'm still starting out with Lua, and would like to write a (relatively) simple proxy using it.

This is what I would like to get to:

1. Listen on port.
2. Accept connection.
3. Since this is a proxy, I'm expecting HTTP (Get/Post etc..)/HTTPS/FTP/whatever requests from my browser.
4. Inspect the request (Just to extract the host and port information?)
5. Create a new socket and connect to the host specified in the request.
6. Relay the exact request as it was received, with POST data and all.
7. Receive the response (header/body/anything else..) and respond to the initial request.
8. Close Connections? I suppose Keep-Alive shouldn't be respected?

I realize it's not supposed to be trivial, but I'm having a lot of trouble setting this up using LuaSockets or Copas --- how do I receive the entire request? Keep receiving until I scan \r\n\r\n? Then how do I pull the post data? and the body? Or accept a "download" file? I read about the "sink", but admittedly didn't understand most of what that meant, so maybe I should read up more on that?

In case it matters, I'm working on a windows machine, using LuaForWindows and am still rather new to Lua. Loving it so far though, tables are simply amazing :)

I discovered lua-http but it seems to have been merged into Xavante (and I didn't find any version for lua 5.1 and LuaForWindows), not sure if it makes my life easier?

Thanks in advance for any tips, pointers, libraries/source I should be looking at etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy as you may think. Requests to proxies and request to servers are different. In [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) you can see that, when querying a proxy, a client include the absolute url of the requested document instead of the usual relative one.

So, as a proxy, you have to parse incomming requests, modify them, query the appropriate servers, and return response.

Parsing incomming requests is quite complex as body length depends on various parameters ( method, content encoding, etc ).

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't thought about it to be honest, but I'm still left unsure how to proceed? Going to take a closer look at lua-http-parser, but I was really expecting an easier time coding "get request + all data -> forward it, recieve response + data -> forward it"

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [lua-http-parser](https://github.com/brimworks/lua-http-parser).

Comment: Thanks! That looks interesting, and seems like it could make parsing the request/response much simpler.